# Build failed on cucumber import

Tags: selenium, maven, build, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am building framework. When I try to build I am getting build failure error on cucumber import. Can anyone help me on this. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: did you add this dependency to your pom.xml? and if so, did you (auto)import the dependencies? (Sidenote: that is not the cucumber.io dependency; are you trying to use a shared library from your organization?)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am able to solve the issue by changing the correct location for step definition in Runner file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue by changing the runner.

Comment: Can you clarify what you changed, so your answer helps the next person with this question?

Comment: I changed the path for step definition and feature files.